# Passing parameters coming from a custom stage in spinnaker to a subsequent stage?

Tags: spinnaker

we are using Spinnaker to automate our deployment pipelines. As part of the pipelines we have some custom stage that generate change tickets in JIRA for the release (some mandate we have from a regulatory perspective). The custom stage then waits for the change ticket to be approved and moves on. This all works perfectly.

What we are now trying is to add another stage at the end of the pipeline that moves the change ticket to done. For this, we would somehow need to be able to catch the JIRA ticket reference in the previous custom stage and pass it to this custom stage which can then move the JIRA ticket to done using the ticket reference that was passed to it.

Did anyone try passing data from one custom stage to another before?

Looking forward to your responses,

Moritz

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a new parameter in your configuration stage:

[image]

2. Now assign the Jira ticket number from your Create ticket stage to this variable. The value can be accessed based on how you call the JIRA api and how you get the output. The output can be accessed by spinnaker expressions, for example I am accessing the output for a stage (type: Find Image name from prod cluster stage) like this ${#stage("stagename")["outputs"]["artifacts"][0]["version"]}. This expression cannot be reused and will be unique to your call and how you get the output. So change the expression accordingly. ${parameters.jiraTicket} = ${#stage("stagename")["outputs"]["artifacts"][0]["version"]}
3. In your 3rd stage you can now use the spinnaker expression ${parameters.jiraTicket} and then close the jira ticket.

You can ignore the steps 1 and 2 and directly use the spinnaker expression from step 2 in step 3 as well.

Comment: Thanks Isaiah, can you add a bit more details how I can have the custom stage return a value that is then assigned to the parameter? my understanding is, that the custom stage executes as a pod on our k8s cluster.

Comment: hmm that I wont be able to as its specific to how you are doing things. If you are running it as a pod, you should write the jira ticket number to DB or in the new custom stage you should query jira to get the right ticket number in the custom stage. 

You should be able to execute webhooks stage: https://spinnaker.io/guides/user/pipeline/triggers/webhooks/
so if you have the the jira parameters, you can try calling this directly from spinnaker stage and you will have the jira ticket number.